# Подключение Aiogram к Crm

Tags: aiogram, crm

Есть бот написанный на aiogram, нужно сделать так, чтобы при написании команды /help боту подключалась Crm и пользователю приходило сообщение о соединении с поддержкой, после этого в Crm появлялся чат с пользователем и сделка.

Comment: Читайте документацию к вашей crm

Comment: @andreymal у меня Crm битрикс